# Use decltype to declare the return type

Tags: c++, pointers, decltype

I've got the following code snippet:

```
int odd[] = { 1,3,5,7,9 };
int even[] = { 0,2,4,6,8 };

// returns a pointer to an array of five int elements
decltype(odd) *arrPtr(int i) {
    return (i % 2) ? &odd : &even; // returns a pointer to the array
}

int main()
{
    int *res1 = arrPtr(3);
    decltype(odd) *res2 = arrPtr(3);
    auto res3 = arrPtr(3);
}
```

For the first line I get the following error message:

> `int (*arrPtr(int i))[5]`
>
> returns a pointer to an array of five int elements
>
> Error: a value of type "`int (*)[5]`" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "`int *`"

Why can't `int*` be used to initialize my return value from `arrayPtr()`? I would have assumed that the compiler is doing an explicit conversion.

Furthermore, what would one use as return type (best practice)?

Comment: Please do never post code on screenshots. And also better prepare a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `odd` is declared as an array of `int`:

```
int odd[5];
```

The type of `odd` is `int[5]` and taking the address (or adding a `*` to `decltype(odd)`) of this array yields an `int(*)[5]`. It seems, you actually want to use the *decayed* type of `odd`:

```
decltype(+odd) arrPtr(int i) {
    return i % 2? odd: even;
}

int main() {
   int*           res1 = arrPtr(3);
   decltype(+odd) res2 = arrPtr(3);
   auto           res3 = arrPtr(3)
}
```

Note this use of unary `+` which forces decay of the array to become a pointer to the first element of the array.

If you really mean to return a pointer to the array, you'd need to use a suitable type when capturing the result (assuming the original implementation):

```
int (*res1)[5]      = arrPtr(3);
decltype(odd)* res2 = arrPtr(3);
auto res3           = arrPtr(3);
```

Note, that this is a pointer to an array of 5 `int`, i.e., you'd access an element of it using

```
(*res1)[3];
```

or

```
res1[0][3];
```

Comment: Now this is something new, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

`int (&)[5]` can decay to `int *`, it is not the case for `int (*)[5]`.

You may change your code to

```
decltype(odd)& arrPtr(int i) {
    return (i % 2) ? odd : even; // returns the reference to the array
}
```

and then

```
int main()
{
    int *res1 = arrPtr(3);
    decltype(odd)& res2 = arrPtr(3); // int (&)[5]
    auto res3 = arrPtr(3); // int*
    const auto& res4 = arrPtr(3); // const int (&)[5]
}
```